# Laravel: Creating route resource for sub directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and creating a spare parts maintenance app.
I created a route resource for spare parts using :

```
Route::resource('/parts' , 'SparePartsController');
```

This works fine.
Later I wanted to also create another route resource for spare parts categories. So I created the controller and used:

```
Route::resource('/parts/categories' , 'SpCategoriesController');
```

But this second resource wont work. When i go to www.myapp.com/parts/categories , I get a blank page. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Try using:
Route::controller('/parts/categories' , 'SpCategoriesController');
And do you have a getIndex() function on your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try to group the routes with a prefix for example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'parts'], function(){

    Route::get('/', 'SparePartsController');
    Route::get('/categories', 'SpCategoriesController');
});
```

This will route all traffic from /parts to the SparePartsController and /parts/categories will call the SpCategoriesController

Look at the documentation for more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups

If you want to call a specific function of the Controller just write:

Route::get('/', 'SparePartsController@functionName')

Answer (score 0):

The SpCategoriesController resource route won't work because SparePartsController resource route is taking precedence over it.

To fix that, place your routes in this order:

```
Route::resource('/parts/categories' , 'SpCategoriesController');
Route::resource('/parts' , 'SparePartsController')
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: @BitOne Great! Mark the answer as correct if it helped :-)